# Как создать свою агрегатную фукнцию в Access?

Tags: access

Всем известна агрегатная функция Sum. В качестве параметра ей указывается атрибут, а при её выполнении СУБД скармливает ей массив (или коллекцию, результат другого запроса?) чисел, которые она суммирует. (плохо описал)

Требуется создать свою агрегатную функцию, которая бы подсчитывала, скажем, среднее геометрическое.

На просторах интернета предлагают создать макрос примерно следующего содержания:

```
Public Function UnionStr(ААА As ???) As Double
Dim txt As String
txt = "select ..."
UnionStr = CurrentProject.Connection.Execute(txt).ЕщёЧтоТоДелаем()
End Function
```

Но эта функция **не агрегатная**. Она выполняет дополнительный запрос и что-то с ним делает.

1. Что должно быть на месте вопросительных знаков, чтобы функция могла принять данные для расчёта?
2. Как указать Access'у, что эта функция агрегатная?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никак. Среднее геометрическое считайте средним арифметическим и логарифмами.